# devops - selenium- jira integration into jenkins

Tags: selenium, jira, devops, jira-rest-api

I am working on one devops project, from selenium I am running test script and a log file is getting generated. How to configure jira to read the log file generated by selenium.. I want to go with API approch but unable to do so. Jenkins I am using as a CI tool here. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "jira reading the logfile"? What would you like to see in jira and in which places?

Comment: from selenium after running the test cases, I want that jira should log bugs for the failed test cases, which is not happening right now. Failed cases are getting recorded in a logfile.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Generally it's a better approach to display your test results in Jenkins instead of creating issues for them automatically. You didn't mention what technology you use (nodejs, java, ...), but typically you let your test runner generate a test results file that jenkins can interprete, so it will display the results nicely. There are various jenkins plugins that can help with that.

If you want to go a step further and still create issues automatically, you can script that in a separate step of your jenkins job, using the JIRA REST API and a scripting language of your choice. It just comes down to parsing the results file and let your script create issues for the failures.